# My xpath for my selenium instagram bot clicks on a profile instead of popping up the like box

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram

```
Liked by user_name and 990 others
```

If you're familiar with instagram this is what it looks like at the bottom of the page when you click on a picture, and for some reason no matter what xpath I pick, it clicks on "user_name" instead of the "990 others". When It's a simple:

```
990 likes
```

It works perfectly. Believe me I've tried all kinds of xpaths:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'liked_by')]
//a[@class = 'zV_Nj']
//a[@class = 'zV_Nj']/span
//section/div/div/a/span
```

I have tried to specifically avoid the "user_name" profile with this xpath:

```
//section/div/div[2]/a[2]
```

But nothing works, it keeps clicking on the profile. Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong? My goal is to get the likers box to popup. I've been at it for a few hours now, please help.

```
<section class="EDfFK ygqzn">
<div class="                  Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5   vwCYk                                                                                                               ">
<div class="                  Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                       ItkAi                                                                       ">
<div class="                  Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">
<div class="KcRNL QnLYV  ">
<span class="_2dbep " role="link" tabindex="0" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">
img class="_6q-tv" src="https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/6e8be84d80c13692826b2ed1d22ecd37/5C8AFF58/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26066662_205753880002771_3331346998950363136_n.jpg" alt="ewapelak's profile picture">
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Nm9Fw">
Liked by 
<a class="FPmhX notranslate cqXBL" title="ewapelak" href="/ewapelak/">ewapelak</a> 
and 
<a class="zV_Nj" href="/p/Bqrkrc5Fpwo/liked_by/">
<span>994</span> others
</a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML ? Do people need to have an account to get to the appropriate view?

Comment: Yes, you need an account and you need to have somebody that you follow liking the post so you can get the "Liked by "Your_friend" and 999 other people"

Comment: Do those class attributes really have all that white space?

Comment: Yes, do you want a screencap of the whole thing?

Comment: I think a https://pastebin.com/  would be more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FjuZ5La1

Comment: It looks like a huge mess.

Comment: What happens if you use a css selector? find_element_by_css_selector("[href$='/liked_by/']").click()  ?

Comment: It still clicks on the profile instead of the liked by.

Comment: FYI it needs to click on "others" to pop up the box.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work finally, I used a class_name selector. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)

Comment: How do I give you som karma/upvote or whatever it's called here?

Comment: It's not a problem :-) You worked it out.